# Adding a new line inside a for loop. C programming

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, newline

Hi it's my first year in college and we have a homework in C programming about arrays. And I managed to write my code but my only problem is adding the spacing or new line while still inside the for loop and a user can still input. the spacing or new line is after `number[2]` thus, separating `number[3]` and `number[4]` from the rest.

The desired output is this:

```
Enter number [0]: 70
Enter number [1]: 89
Enter number [2]: 90    (Enter Key)
Enter number [3]: 76
Enter number [4]: 78 

number [0]: 70
number [1]: 89
number [2]: 90    

 

number [3]: 76
number [4]: 78

 

Highest Grade : 90
Lowest Grade  : 70


Average Grade:
```

This is my code. (sorry for bad spacing or formatting I'm a beginner)

```
int main(){
    
    int Agrades[5];
    int BGrades=5;
    int average=0;
    int highest, lowest;
    for (int i=0; i<BGrades; ++i){
        printf("Enter Number[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",&Agrades[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<BGrades; ++i){
    printf("\nNumber[%d]:%d",i, Agrades[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<BGrades; ++i)
    average+=Agrades[i];
    average= average/5;

     lowest=highest=Agrades[0];
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
         if(lowest>Agrades[i])
          lowest=Agrades[i];   
         if(highest<Agrades[i])
          highest=Agrades[i];       
    }
     printf("\n\nHighest Grade: %d", highest);
     printf("\nLowest Grade: %d", lowest);

    printf("\n\nAverage Grade: %d", average);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output from the code that I made:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bATSp.png)

Comment: You mean they can press enter and make a new line? That's normal for console programs. There's not really anything you can do about it.

Comment: Being a beginner is not an excuse for poor code formatting. Use the same formatting used in your learning material. Correctly formatted code is very important, especially for beginners.

Comment: Whenever my classmates and I try to press enter to make a new line. There's no new line or space between number[2] and number[3] when the results of our inputs are printed.

Comment: Sorry guys for excuse. But it's really heard to learn on a online class and no given reading materials and we just rely on our teacher teaching us on what he can do on a limited time.

Comment: You have shown the desired output. What is the actual output?

Comment: @klutt i'll add my actual output at the post.

Comment: @klutt https://i.stack.imgur.com/bATSp.png

Comment: it's a good trait to put newlines `\n` at the end of the line rather than at the begining.
i.e. `"\nLowest Grade: %d"` -> `"Lowest Grade: %d\n"`

Comment: @Lans Please don't add pictures of text

Comment: Adding enter key in code will do nothing at the program output. If you want to add newline in output add some printf("\n") statement when you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `if` check should do the trick

```
  for (int i = 0; i < BGrades; ++i)
  {
    printf("\nNumber[%d]:%d", i, Agrades[i]);
    if (i == 2)
    {
      puts("\n");    // or printf("\n"); to skip just 1 line
    }
  }
```

else if u wish to add the `\n` character while the user is inputting, then it would be good to implement using strings, add `\n` during the input phase and then parse the strings to ints while printing them or just print them as string if datatypes are not an issue.

If u wish to implement the second version, specify so i can modify my answer

The current output is:

```
>> gcc -o test test.c
>> ./test
Enter Number[0]:1
Enter Number[1]:2
Enter Number[2]:3
Enter Number[3]:4
Enter Number[4]:5

Number[0]:1
Number[1]:2
Number[2]:3


Number[3]:4
Number[4]:5

Highest Grade: 5
Lowest Grade: 1

Average Grade: 3
```

Comment: The first version worked great and it's good enough to pass to my teacher! thank you so much! but if u can and if u want, can you please give an example of the second version and elaborate it a little bit? so I can further my knowledge about C programming. Thank you so much again.